# Why doesn't typescript compiler warn about overriding getter with a variable?

Tags: typescript

If I override a getter with a variable I get runtime error. The following code compiles without any warning or error (for ES5+):

```
class Parent {
    public get foo(): number { return 0; }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    constructor(public foo: number) { super(); }
}

var child = new Child(0);
```

However running the compiled JS results in:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property foo of #<Parent> which has only a getter
    at new Child
```

Comment: I can't say why `tsc` doesn't error on it, but I can tell you that this is an interesting place where TypeScript and the [class fields JavaScript proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields) work differently. TypeScript uses [[Set]] semantics (essentially: assignment) to create the public property in the subclass; JavaScript's class fields proposal uses [[DefineProperty]] semantics. Among other things, that means that the JS version of this works just fine, replacing the base `foo` accessor with a data property: https://jsfiddle.net/tjcrowder/pfokre13/

Comment: *(It was the subject of* much *discussion as the proposal progressed.)*